# Same command outputs different value on different devices

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, pip

I have two Raspberry Pi 3.
When I do

```
(tfenv)pi@raspberrypi:~ $ pip install opencv-python==
```

on the first Raspberry Pi, I get :

```
 Collecting opencv-python
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python== 
(from versions: 3.1.0.0, 3.1.0.1, 3.1.0.2, 3.1 .0.3, 3.1.0.5, 3.2.0.6, 3.2.0.7) No matching distribution found for opencv-python==
```

On the second Raspberry Pi, I get:

```
   Collecting opencv-python
      Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python (from versions: )
    No matching distribution found for opencv-python
```

I suspect that to happen due to the different version of Raspbian installed on each. Raspberry Pi 2 has `Strech` installed and Raspberry Pi 2 has `Jessie`
Am I correct or something else is wrong?

UPDATE

I used `pip install --verbose opencv-python==` and here is the result:

Rasberry Pi that has pip not working

```
 Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2b/31/cc5cf31258dc2cbb50dd1b046164add33804eab7af036d86aa68d45c7f6c/opencv_python-3.4.1.15-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl#sha256=2cea809afe32cdccf97d66b131afc0fed80076244fb77b68ad9bf016d9cdc261 (from https://pypi.org/simple/opencv-python/); it is not compatible with this Python
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python== (from versions: )
Cleaning up...
No matching distribution found for opencv-python==
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/.conda/envs/tfenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/_internal/basecommand.py", line 228, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/pi/.conda/envs/tfenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 291, in run
    resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
  File "/home/pi/.conda/envs/tfenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 103, in resolve
    self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req)
  File "/home/pi/.conda/envs/tfenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 257, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "/home/pi/.conda/envs/tfenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 210, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    self.require_hashes
  File "/home/pi/.conda/envs/tfenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 245, in prepare_linked_requirement
    req.populate_link(finder, upgrade_allowed, require_hashes)
  File "/home/pi/.conda/envs/tfenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 307, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/home/pi/.conda/envs/tfenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 533, in find_requirement
    'No matching distribution found for %s' % req
pip._internal.exceptions.DistributionNotFound: No matching distribution found for opencv-python==
```

Raspberry Pi that has pip working correctly

Comment: Are they both up-to-date?

Comment: Do you mean sudo apt-get update ? Yes I did that

Comment: Also `sudo apt upgrade`?

Comment: I did both but it still gives the same result

Comment: have you tried the non pip [version](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/python-opencv)

Comment: Run `pip --version` on both Pi's and compare the output.

Comment: @hoefling both are pip version 10.0.1

Comment: Hmm, can you then run `pip install --verbose opencv-python==` and add both logs to the question?

Comment: Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/21/b0/370a3734e15e30c961eb21b4b42c1094deb101483d3982a4b516736e4a14/opencv_python-3.2.0.6-cp35-cp35m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl#sha256=61c3edd23e4efc82efd5b0441d6cbe2e10ecf7d400b366abdee397099b255f02 (from https://pypi.org/simple/opencv-python/); it is not compatible with this Python

Comment: @hoefling it is saying this many times over

Comment: Question updated

Comment: I took a closer look at the `opencv-python` package on PyPI. They don't provide a prebuilt wheel for your architecture (which would be `aarch64`), so you won't be able to install `opencv-python` from PyPI neither on one, nor the other RaspberryPi. What does `python3 -c "from setuptools import pep425tags; print(pep425tags.get_platform())"` return? is it `linux_aarch64` or `linux_armv7l`?

Comment: For `linux_aarch64`, you can resort to an unofficial build for arm64: `pip install opencv-python-aarch64`. For `linux_armv7l`, I found a [list of prebuilt wheels for armv6l and armv7l](https://www.piwheels.hostedpi.com/simple/opencv-python/) - the one matching your platform should be installable via `pip install https://www.piwheels.hostedpi.com/simple/opencv-python/opencv_python-3.4.1.15-cp34-cp34m-linux_armv7l.whl`.

Comment: (tfenv)pi@raspberrypi:~/Downloads/opencv-3.3.0-source/build $ arch
armv7l

Comment: My architecture is armv7l

Comment: Try the second command I posted in the last comment and tell if the installation succeeds.