# Pip install tensorflow not working

Tags: python, tensorflow, raspberry-pi, pip

When I do pip install tensorflow, it says that there is no matching distribution. I already updated pip.

```
(tfenv)pi@raspberrypi:~/Downloads/opencv-3.3.0-source/build $ pip install tensorflow
Collecting tensorflow
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow
(tfenv)pi@raspberrypi:~/Downloads/opencv-3.3.0-source/build $ pip --version
pip 10.0.1 from /home/pi/.conda/envs/tfenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip (python 3.4)
```

I get the [same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50791252/same-command-outputs-different-value-on-different-devices) problem when I try install opencv through pip. I tried this command on another raspberry pi and everything works fine.

Comment: Same issue as in your other question: there is no prebuilt wheel of `tensorflow` for ARM architectures, so `pip` correctly does not install anything. You stated that you have the `linux_armv7l` platform, so you have two choices: either look for unofficial wheels - [here is v1.0.1 prebuilt](https://github.com/samjabrahams/tensorflow-on-raspberry-pi/releases/), install via `pip install https://github.com/samjabrahams/tensorflow-on-raspberry-pi/releases/download/v1.0.1/tensorflow-1.0.1-cp34-cp34m-linux_armv7l.whl`.

Comment: Or build one yourself from source. [Here is a step-by-step tutorial for building on 32bit arm](http://cudamusing.blogspot.com/2015/11/building-tensorflow-for-jetson-tk1.html), although it may be somewhat outdated. Also, you may easily run out of memory on RaspberryPi, so setting up a cross compiler with armv7l support on a linux desktop would be preferable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the latest version of pip in order to install tensorflow or openCV. You can upgrade pip using the below command:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

After upgrading Pip, it should work fine.