# How to fix "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python"

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, pip, raspbian

I am trying to make some basic facial recognition with my raspberry pi using OpenCV-python, however, I am unable to install OpenCV-python using pip3.

I tried to follow this guide 
https://pysource.com/2018/10/31/raspberry-pi-3-and-opencv-3-installation-tutorial/
once this didn't work I tried using a fresh os and upgrading python to no avail.

This is what happens when I input the pip3 command

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ pip3  install opencv-python
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting opencv-python
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for opencv-python
```

I expect that opencv-python should start installing

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50791252/same-command-outputs-different-value-on-different-devices#comment88605830_50791252

Comment: When I follow that I get to the "Links for opencv-python" however I can not find a version that goes with my cp and cpm type. My raspberry pi is running cp36 and cp36m and is linux_armv7l, however, the latest version of opencv-python on that website is cp35 and cpm35. When I try and use the version on the website I get an error message saying "ERROR: opencv_python-3.4.4.19-cp35-cp35m-linux_armv7l.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform."

Comment: Then there is no wheels for your Python. Either use Python 3.5 or compile from sources.

Comment: After quite a lot of troubleshooting that worked wonderfully, thank you :)